# Know when qr code is being scanned

Tags: php, qr-code

As the title says..Is there a way that i can put a qr code in my webpage and when a users scans it whith his phone then the webpage(opened in a desktop computer for example) redirects the user to another page.NOT on the phone.I want to redirect the user when he scans the qr code but not on the phone..only in the browser he has opened in his desktop computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and fairly straight forward.

When you display a QR code, you encode a URL like www.domain.com/scan.php?user=xxxxx (xxxx could be IP address, or unique session ID etc).

When this URL is accessed (via the phone after scanning) it updates a database value for the user identifier.

Then you have a JavaScript polling on the desktop version every 5 seconds or something. Each time it checks the database value (bool field), if true then it redirects the desktop version.

Comment: Great idea.Will try it and post back.

Comment: This would require that the scanner automatically opened any link (which they don't), but it OP is happy with somebody having to click the link on the mobile device, then fair enough. :)

Comment: @JonStirling My experience of QR scanning apps if it's a URL they automatically open the link (EG: [QRReader for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/qr-reader-for-iphone/id368494609)).

Comment: @JamieBicknell Seriously? Well that's a massive security hole! But if that's the case, then +1 for the answer.